# Logging of method execution time

Tags: java, logging, groovy

In java/groovy application I am using `org.slf4j.Logger`
I like to log method execution time and proposing to use following code

```
def startTime
LOGGER.isDebugEnabled() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

doSomething()

LOGGER.debug("Execution took {}ms", (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))
```

I think this code is 'ugly'.
Can anyone suggest something more elegant ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make the code look less ugly:

Change

```
def startTime
LOGGER.isDebugEnabled() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

to

```
def startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

I am not a fan of `isDebugEnabled` for these one liners. You will not see any performance difference without it.

Comment: I would agree, if ANYWHERE it should be at the point where the actual logging occurs rather than at a simple get of the system time. But this log is just a simple string so it's not really necessary there either.

Answer (score 9):

You can probably use this class to calculate elapsed time.

```
public class StopWatch {

    /* Private Instance Variables */
    /** Stores the start time when an object of the StopWatch class is initialized. */
    private long startTime;

    /**
     * Custom constructor which initializes the {@link #startTime} parameter.
     */
    public StopWatch() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the elapsed time (in seconds) since the time the object of StopWatch was initialized.
     * 
     * @return Elapsed time in seconds.
     */
    public double getElapsedTime() {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return (double) (endTime - startTime) / (1000);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class SWTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

        doSomething();

        LOGGER.debug("Execution took in seconds: ", (stopWatch.getElapsedTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - This is neat, you can still remove `LOGGER.isDebugEnabled() {` :)

Comment: @aa8y - Is it absolutely needed to compute the elapsed time? What if we just use `stopwatch.toString()` to log the elapsed time?

Comment: Well that won't work with the way the code is. But you can override the `toString` method to return a string which you can use to log.

Answer (score 4):

When measuring a difference between 2 points in time, you should use System.nanoTime(), the millis variant should be used when you are actually interested in measuring the time (from the epoch value) but not when you want to measure a difference in time as precisely as possible.

Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

> Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's
>   high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 4):

The current suggestions don't seem to be taking advantage of the fact that the OP is using `Groovy`.

Here's my take on it:

```
class CodeTimer {

    /**
     * Time how long it takes to run a piece of code
     *
     * @param closure code to execute and time
     * @return time elapsed in nano seconds
     */
    static final long time(closure) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime()

        closure()

        return System.nanoTime() - startTime
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
def duration = CodeTimer.time({
    sql.executeUpdate(QUERY)
})

log.debug("Execution took ${duration}ns")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use AOP and Java annotations, to make your code cleaner. I would recommend to use [`@Loggable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-loggable.html) annotation and an AspectJ aspect from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/) (I'm a developer):

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
  // do something
}
```

All calls to this method will be logged, with all parameters and execution time, through SLF4J.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use jcabi-aspects as noted in your answer, only I am using it on an entire class(so the class is annotated, not every single method in it), but I get nothing printed in the log. Should there be any configuration done first?

Comment: Yes, you should weave your classes, as explained in http://aspects.jcabi.com/index.html (send a message to [jcabi Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jcabi), we'll discuss in details)

Answer (score 0):

If you used spring:

```
StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
    watch.start();
    for(int i=0; i < 1000000; i++){
        Object obj = new Object();
    }    
    watch.stop();

    System.out.println("Total execution time to create 1000K objects in Java using StopWatch in millis: "                + watch.getTotalTimeMillis());
```